# Get Origin of Column of View in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-catalog

Suppose I have two tables

```
create table user_information1 (
  user_id int not null,
  age int not null,
  primary key (user_id),
);
create table user_information2 (
  user_id int not null,
  height decimal(1,2) not null,
  primary key (user_id),
);
```

and a view

```
create view collected_information as
  select a.customer_id AS id,
    a.age,
    b.age
   from user_information1 a,
   user_information2 b
where 
a.user_id = b.user_id;
```

With pg_depend it is possible to see which tables the view depends on. Can I also find in the pg_catalog the information which column comes from which table? This means for example the age column comes from user_information1 without assuming that the columns have the same name and I look for columns with the same name.
The select I use to find the depending views is the following:

```
SELECT
    e.nspname,
    c.relname,
    f.nspname,
    d.relname
FROM
    pg_depend    a,
    pg_rewrite   b,
    pg_class     c,
    pg_class     d,
    pg_namespace e,
    pg_namespace f
WHERE
    c.oid = b.ev_class
AND b.oid = a.objid
AND c.relkind = 'v'
AND a.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass
AND a.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
AND a.deptype = 'n'
AND e.oid = c.relnamespace
AND f.oid = d.relnamespace
AND a.refobjid = d.oid
AND c.oid <> d.oid;
```

Comment: But that's exactly the information you'll find in `pg_depend`, isn't it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So I added the select I use to find depending views but is there a possibility to find this also for each column in specific? I didn't find any OID which could be linked to `pg_attribute`

Comment: It is `objsubid` and `refobjsubid` that refer to the columns (join with `pg_attribute.attnum`).

Comment: In my current SQL I use the column `objid` from `pg_depend` to join with the column `oid` from `pg_rewrite`. My view for which I then want to determine the dependencies is stored in `ev_class` from `pg_rewrite`. Here I have no column numbers, or are these stored somewhere else? `objid` of `pg_depend` is always 0 in the join from above since it is a different object.

Comment: There will be dependencies between the query rewrite rule and the columns of the underlying tables.